# How to resolve TokenMismatchException in Laravel 5 App

Tags: laravel-5.1

I have developed a laravel 5 app and everything works fine except that I occationally get TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53. I can't seem to figure out the cause. This happens mostly during login. I used the laravel built-in trait to implement authentication. Below is my sample logout method.

```
public function getLogout()
    {
        Auth::logout();
        Session::forget('cart_id');
        Session::forget('is_supervisor');
        Session::forget('is_manager');
        return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
    }
```

Each time the exception occurs, I have to reload the page and login again before this works. Below is a sample of my login form:

```
{!! Form::open(array('class' => 'form-horizontal', 'role' => 'form')) !!}
     <div class="form-group">
         {!! Form::label('username', trans('home.username'), array('class' => 'col-sm-3 control-label')) !!}
             <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-5">
                {!! Form::text('username', null, array('required' => 'required', 'class' => 'form-control input-sm')) !!}
                        </div>
          </div>
{!! Form::close() !!}
```

When I check the page source, the csrf token is always available. What could possibly be the problem. I am using laravel 5.1.* and SESSION_DRIVER=file in .env.

**Edit**

// Authentication routes...

```
Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

Comment: Can you figure out when does this error occur?

Comment: This error occur occationally when I try to login. When I enter username and password and submit, it shows the exception. To solve, I have to do a page reload not even a refresh and login again before it works. This happens occationally not all the time. What really could be the problem. I am using the form helper to build my form which adds the Cross site Request Forgery tokens automatically. What could be wrong???

Comment: Can you edit your post and add your routes declaration for login? Also if you have any middleware that this route goes through add it also.

Comment: I have added the login routes @TheFallen. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

CSRF Protection (Cross-Site-Request-Forgery) saves you from unwanted actions on web application.
The token is generated when rendering form and expired after some time.
If you have the form opened too long, you get TokenMismatchException.

Did you notice the problem shortly after reload page (form)?

Try to add
`{{ csrf_field() }}` to your form and check if it helps.

Comment: I notice the problem when the user tries to login @mikes. When the user enters the username and password, and click login, the exception happens. This doesn't happen all the time though. Sometimes it works just fine, other times the exception is raised. `{!! Form::open() !!}` adds the token automatically