# Laravel 5.2 TokenMismatchException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'd like to write a code in Laravel 5.2 which would upload photos, my problem is that once I start uploading many photos at once the site goes down.

It gives me this error: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67:

This error should appear only when the {{ csrf_field() }}, is missing from the form, but in this case it isn't, it's right there.

It works perfectly with less images. What could be the problem?

Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = array(
        'picturess' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png',
    );
    $messages = array(
        'mimes' => 'A feltöltetni kívánt kép nem felel meg a kritériumoknak. (Ilyen lehet a kép kiterjesztése: jpeg, jpg, bmp vagy png. A kép se lehet bármekkora.)',
        'integer' => 'A beírt szőveg nem szám.',
        'required' => 'Ennek a mezőnek a kitőltése kötelező.',
    );
    $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $messages);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        $messages = $validator->messages();
        return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);

    }
    if (Input::hasFile('pictures')) {
        $files = $request::file('pictures');
        $file_count = count($files);
        $uploadcount = 0;
        $destinationPath = 'uploads';
        $userId = Auth::user()->id;
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            if ($file->isValid()) {
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

                $pictureFileName = $this->makePictureFileName(0, $extension);
                $thumbnailPictureFileName = $this->makePictureFileName(1, $extension);
                Log::info('pictureFileName: '.$pictureFileName);

                if ($file->move($destinationPath, $pictureFileName)) {
                    $uploadcount++;
                    $img = Image::make($destinationPath . '/' . $pictureFileName);
                    //$img = Image::make($file->getClientOriginalName());
                    $img->resize(277, null, function ($constraint) {
                        $constraint->aspectRatio();
                    });
                    $img->save($destinationPath . '/' . $thumbnailPictureFileName);
                    $picture = new Picture;
                    $picture->filename = $pictureFileName;
                    $picture->thumbnail_filename = $thumbnailPictureFileName;
                    $picture->user_id = $userId;
                    $picture->save();
                }

            } else {
                Session::flash('picture-error', 'A feltöltetni kívánt kép nem megfelelő. (Valószínűleg túl nagy.)');
                return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
            }
        }
        if ($uploadcount == $file_count) {
            Session::flash('success', 'A képek feltöltése sikeres.');
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
        }
    }
    //return Redirect::to('pictures/create');
    return redirect()->back()->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
}
```

View

```
@extends('layouts.site')

@section('content')
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">

            {!! Form::open(array('method' =>'POST', 'url' => 'pictures', 'class' => 'uk-form', 'files'=> true)) !!}
            {{ csrf_field() }}


                <div class="form-group">
                    {!! Form::label('pictures', 'Kép', array('class' => '')) !!}
                    <div class="uk-form-controls">
                        {!! Form::file('pictures[]', array('class' => '','multiple'=>true)) !!}
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="uk-button">Küldés</button>
                </div>


            @if ($errors->has('success'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <p>{{ $errors->first('success') }}</p>
                </div>
            @endif
            @if(Session::has('picture-error'))
                <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                    <p class="errors">{!! Session::get('error') !!}</p>
                </div>
            @endif
            @if (count($errors) > 0)
                <div class="alert alert-danger">
                    <ul>
                        @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                        @endforeach
                    </ul>
                </div>
            @endif
            {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'SiteController@index');
    Route::get('admin', 'AdminController@index');
    Route::resource('pictures', 'PicturesController');
    Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
    Route::auth();
});
```

Comment: On successful upload of an image, where are you redirecting the user? It looks as if you're flashing the success message to sessions but then it seems to be redirecting back with input. I believe the token will produce an error since it has already been "used", so you might try to send them to the route with a fresh instance, which should create a new token and avoid the error.

Comment: I have similar problem here. I just haven't figure out what is wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37717449/how-to-resolve-tokenmismatchexception-in-laravel-5-app

Comment: If I'm using this code to redirect the user return redirect('pictures/create'); should it work properly? Because it seems to be the same, it doesn't really work.

Answer (score 2):

`{!! Form::open...` will automatically add CSRF field protection, so you don't need this `{{ csrf_field() }}`.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I appreciate it

Comment: @FerencStraub Glad I could help :) Please mark the answer as correct if it solved your problem.